# Kafka PartitionStrategy + horizontal scaling

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm confused to what degree partition assignment is a client side concern `partition.assignment.strategy` and what part is handled by Kafka.

For example, say I have one kafka topic with 100 partitions.

If I make 1 app that runs 5 threads of consumers, with a `partition.assignment.strategy` of RangeAssignor then I should get 5 consumers each consuming 25 partitions.

Now if I scale this app by deploying it 4 times, and using the same consumer group. Will kafka first divide 25 partitions to each of these apps on its side, and only then are these 25 partitions further subdivided by the app using the PartitionStrategy?

Which would result neatly in 4 apps with 5 consumers each, consuming 5 partitions each.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the default Assignors is well documented in the Javadocs.

RangeAssignor is the default Assignor, see its Javadoc for example of assignment it generates: http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html

If you have 20 consumers using RangeAssignor that are consuming from a topic with 100 partitions, each consumer will be assigned 5 partitions.

Because RangeAssignor assigns partitions topic by topic, it can create really unbalanced assignments if you have topics with very few partitions. In that case, [RoundRobinAssignor](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html) works better

Comment: Don't know why this answer was downvoted, it is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

As part of group management, the consumer will keep track of the list of consumers that belong to a particular group and will trigger a rebalance operation if any one of the following events are triggered:

1. Number of partitions change for any of the subscribed topics
2. A subscribed topic is created or deleted
3. An existing member of the consumer group is shutdown or fails.
4. > A new member is added to the consumer group.

Most likely point no. 4 is your case and the strategy used will be the same(partition.assignment.strategy). Not that this is not applicable if you have explicitly specified the partition to be consumed by your consumer